# How to create a search engine that generates images of ingredients for a particular meal?

Tags: django, web

I am using Django to create a web application where it includes a search engine that allows users to input a meal and the search engine provides the ingredients for the meal in images. So far, I have implemented ElasticSearch as my search engine. However, now I have the issue of gathering data of the images for the list of ingredients for the particular meal.

How would I get the data?

Answer (score 0):

You may enrich your data-set, so the information of ingredients also contains an URI to the referring picture/thumbnail. With this information, your application is able to load these images after receiving search results. That's how we usually handle detail pages or images.

Comment: I want to create something similar to "Search Shapes" on draw.io